# Drupal: "Send email" action not working to send email to poster of comment

Tags: php, email, drupal

I have successfully set up email notifications on my client's blog for administrators when new comments are posted and am now trying to set it up to send a thank-you email to the poster of the comment as well. I set it up using triggers and actions as described [here](http://www.jasonhooker.com/index.php?q=configure-drupal-notification-on-new-comments).

I put in `[comment:author:mail]` in the "Recipient" field on the action configuration form as suggested in the note right below that field, but it seems that it never sends the email. I initially tested it using my own email address and it worked fine, then I posted a comment as an anonymous user using two different email addresses of mine but never received an email. Why is `[comment:author:mail]` not working? I'm using other variables in the body of the email (e.g. `[comment:node:title]`) and they're working fine.

I tried using Maillog as was suggested on Drupal Answers, which verified that the problem isn't with mail delivery but rather with the email not being populated correctly.

Here's a screenshot that shows the email to the administrator is working correctly, but not the thank-you email:

[image]

Note: I originally posted this question on Drupal Answers. I hope it's not a problem that I'm re-posting it here, since no one there offered a resolution.

---

I solved it thanks to the accepted answer below, and thanks to a comment on Drupal Answers - I needed to use `[comment:mail]` instead of `[comment:author:mail]` so it would work with anonymous commenters too. I didn't need to create a custom field, as it turned out. For more info see https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/126814/13378

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The token `[comment:author:mail]` can only be used with registered users.

Take a look at *commet.token.inc*

```
if (($author_tokens = token_find_with_prefix($tokens, 'author')) && $account = user_load($comment->uid)) {
  $replacements += token_generate('user', $author_tokens, array('user' => $account), $options);
}
```

Unregistered users (anonymous users) will have uid 0.

Uid 0 is actually a user, tho it has no name, pass, or other information.

Comment: Thanks very much for this...I'm guessing I will need to use a separate module then if I want it to work with anonymous users too. I'll give this one a try: https://www.drupal.org/project/thank_you_commenter

Comment: You can add a new field to the comment entity from the field UI (/admin/structure/types/manage/[CONTENTTYPE]/comment/fields) and use that as an email address field. 

Tokens for that field will be something like `[comment:field_customfield]`

It would also be nice if you accepted my prev post.

Comment: I was planning to accept your post, but it didn't provide an alternative suggestion so I was going to test out alternatives first...but now you have provided one, so thank you.

Comment: With regard to a custom field, there is already an email field that commenters see, so will I need to hide the default field in order to avoid having 2 email fields show up once I create the custom one?

Comment: Solved it thanks to a comment on Drupal Answers - I needed to use `[comment:mail]` instead of `[comment:author:mail]` so it would work with anonymous commenters too. I didn't need to create a custom field, as it turned out. For more info see http://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/126814/13378